# Unable to add navigation menu url with dynamic parameters in Community Builder

Tags: community, navigation, menu, navigation-menu

I am trying to set up a new navigation menu set in community builder, but am receiving an error when trying to navigate to User Profile and User Setting pages.

I have googled a bit, and seen the advice to update the url to something like "profile/home" but when I change the url (to anything other than what is there) I am unable to save the menu.

Is there any way around this?

[image]
[image]